# Jboss : Unable to get threaddump

Tags: java, jboss, jstack

I am trying to get threaddump for my Jboss Application but I am getting below error. Is there any workaround of fixing this or any other way of getting threaddump.

```
$ jstack -l -F 11815
Attaching to process ID 11815, please wait...
WARNING: Hotspot VM version 25.51-b02-1.035 does not match with SA version . You may see unexpected results.
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.51-b02-1.035
Deadlock Detection:

No deadlocks found.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a kill -3 on Linux which will give you a thread dump.

Comment: And it will stdout or save into a file automaticaly ?

Comment: See this post and decide which best suits what you need:  https://access.redhat.com/solutions/18178